# How to calculate energy added to grid using active and reactive power?

Tags: power-supply, solar-energy, energy-harvesting, power-grid, meter

I have recently installed solar system that adds energy to the grid. My utility company has installed bi-directional meter at my place to record energy consumed as well as energy added to the grid.

Energy consumed is recorded in meter as kWh which is pretty usual however energy added to grid is given in kVARh, I assume they call it reactive energy. Meter provides positive active energy and positive reactive energy readings.

Is there a way I can calculate how many units I have added to the grid?

Comment: Fawad, The kVARs monitoring is usually a way for utilities to *penalize* someone -- make them pay *more* because of the added current carrying capacity it requires. In no way does this represent useful power that you've provided to the utility. If they are paying you *only* for kVARs, you are being cheated in my opinion. But you need to say what's really going on here. I don't know what they are doing with that monitoring. Perhaps there is a combined formula they use. No idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally thrown off by your statement that *energy added to grid is given in kVARh* because all GTI’s that I know have no reactive energy supplied to the grid because by design they are active pf corrected to 1. So verify please and provide more details.

However some high power lower quality GTI’s do have harmonic distortion and have been known to induce circulating currents in good GTI’s with low impedance on these harmonics and raised the currents in neighbouring solar farms enough to raise the currents 20% and blown 80A fuses with generated sine power going out and absorbed harmonics coming in. But this might or not be relevant.

====

VARs are reactive power but monitoring this alone is not enough to see real energy transferred.

Web and meter reading features ought to be available to monitor actual values depending on service provider. I know Huawei converters have excellent web stats with an ethernet link.

Comment: I have monitoring app which tells me KWH energy generated every day, however, i was trying to reconcile the inverter and utility meter.

Comment: Brain fart, right